# Jersey Initialization Functionality: In Application object or in ServletContextListner

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0

I have a Jersey Application using Servlet 3.0. I have a javax.ws.rs.Application used at servlet initialization.

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {....}
```

I have some logic that should run at servlet initialization time. I can put this logic in the constructor of MyApplication or alternatively I can define a ServletContextListner.

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during server startup.
    }

    ...}
```

**What is the correct approach?**

From the Jersey documentation it seems that this is not the intended use case for the Application object.

> JAX-RS provides a deployment agnostic abstract class Application for declaring root resource and provider classes, and root resource and provider singleton instances. A Web service may extend this class to declare root resource and provider classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any logic in the constructor of MyApplication will only be executed on the first request received.

If you need the logic to run at servlet initialization time than you should use the ServletContextListner.